# Register protocol handler for Android app on chromebook/chrome OS to open external link?

Tags: android, chrome-web-store, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I have an Intent Filter in the Manifest file to launch my Android app when a custom URI is clicked. For example, clicking a link with a custom protocol like "XXX://123912967326" from the browser on my Android phone will open my app.

Now, I'm using Google ARC welder to run the same Android app on chromebook/chrome OS. When i try clicking a link with the same custom protocol, I get an error pop up message "Chrome does not support launching an external application to handle 'XXX' links.

Is there any way for my Android app, running on a chromebook through Google ARC, to register 'XXX' links to be opened through the app?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is this with Arc Welder or with the default Android Container on Chrome OS?

Answer (score 0):

This question is outdated as it relied on Arc Welder which was not a supported method for loading Android apps on Chrome OS. Android on Chrome OS now supports deep linking and you can follow the instructions for registering a protocol handler [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking).